# Want to know the reason of rejection of my U.S. B1/B2 Visa, which got refused under 214 (b)?

Tags: visa-refusals, working-visas

> Interviewer: Why you want to visit USA ?
>
> Me: I am going on behalf of my company to take training of new product-fastfill
>
> Interviewer: For how long would you stay there ?
>
> Me: 3 weeks
>
> Interviewer: How many years experience you have with company ?
>
> Me: 2 months
>
> Interviewer: Have you traveled US before ?
>
> Me: No
>
> Interviewer: Have you ever been abroad before ?
>
> Me: No

At this point he rejected my Visa with letter mentioning 214 (b) as the reason. I don't know why he actually rejected it. So could you please clarify, what should I do that it doesn't get rejected when reapplying.

---

I am from India and my interview place was New Delhi

Comment: I am from India and my interview place was New Delhi

Comment: Edit the the question instead of putting valuable information in comments.

Comment: Often 214(b) means you didn't prove to the consular officer that you were going home after your visit.  And with only 2 months working at your new job, that probably factored in to the decision.

Comment: Is there anything in the [official documentation](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/denials.html) that was unclear? I'm afraid nobody here can read your interviewers mind.

Comment: Did you ask the interviewer for his reasons in issuing the rejection?

Comment: "New product training" for three weeks sounds a bit long. What industry is this product of, and why the training couldn't be done online or through web conferencing?

Answer (score 3):

You've been refused a visa and that, in itself, is upsetting. When it denies a visa, the US State Department Bureau of Consular Affairs cites the section(s) under which that decision was made (the legal basis), and a broad explanation. It does not give specifics, in your case or any other, nor does it have to. In trying to understand and, perhaps, how a future application might succeed, look to how [Consular Affairs describes](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/denials.html) what happens and what it means.

> U.S. law generally requires visa applicants to be interviewed by a consular officer at a U.S. Embassy or Consulate. After relevant information is reviewed, the application is approved or denied, based on standards established in U.S. law.
>
> **INA Section 214(b) - Visa Qualifications and Immigrant Intent**
>   **What does a visa denial under INA section 214(b) mean?**
>
> This law applies only to nonimmigrant visa categories. If you are refused a visa under [section 214(b)](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/ineligibilities.html), it means that you:
>
> - Did not sufficiently demonstrate to the consular officer that you qualify for the nonimmigrant visa category you applied for; and/or
> - Did not overcome the presumption of immigrant intent, required by law, by sufficiently demonstrating that you have strong ties to your home country that will compel you to leave the United States at the end of your temporary stay. (H-1B and L visa applicants, along with their spouse and any minor children, are excluded from this requirement.)
>
> **What are considered strong ties to my home country?**
>   Ties are the various aspects of your life that bind you to your home country. Strong ties vary from country to country, city to city, and person to person, but examples include:
>
> - Your job;
> - Your home; and/or
> - Your relationships with family and friends.
>
> While conducting visa interviews, consular officers look at each application individually and consider the applicant's circumstances, travel plans, financial resources, and ties outside of the United States that will ensure the applicant’s departure after a temporary visit.
>
> **Is a refusal under section 214(b) permanent?**
>   No. A refusal, or ineligibility, under section 214(b) is for that specific application, so once a case is closed, the consular section cannot take any further action. There is no appeal process. If you feel there is additional information that should be considered related to the visa decision, or there are significant changes in your circumstances since your last application, you may reapply for a visa. To reapply, you must complete a new application form, pay the application fee, and schedule an appointment for a new interview. Review the w[ebsite of the U.S. Embassy or Consulate](http://www.usembassy.gov/) where you plan to reapply to learn about any reapplication procedures.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this rejection seems to be your work experience in company is just 2 months. With in 2 months company sending you for training seems little fishy. As per my experience consular officers prefer or trust atleast the 2 years of current job.